# how to get the full path of downloaded image?

Tags: jquery, download

```
<img id='imgt' src='01.jpg' alt='img'>
<input type='text' id='inputnewimg'>
```

I fill the input with some img url, for example - https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QX4j_zHAlw8/maxresdefault.jpg

**js**

```
$('#inputnewimg').keypress(function(e) {
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var abc = $(this).val();
    var dl = document.createElement("a");
    dl.href = abc;
    dl.download = true;
    document.body.appendChild(dl);
    dl.click();
}
});
```

The above code downloads the image to default local folder (Downloads).
Is there a way to dinamically set another destination folder, and get the image path and name, because I want the new img to be the source of `#imgt` automatically?

Comment: I don't believe so. at least not in an off-the-shelf web browser.

Comment: @KevinB, Thanks. Do you think there is maybe a solution by converting the image into base64 and... I'm not sure...or clone the image using canvas, without downloading at all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't unfortunately.

The only thing you can do is change the filename before downloading.

```js
// You can use the code below to match the filename
var srcOfImage = "http://mywebsite.com/images/beautiful_logo.png?even=withParamaters";
var filename = srcOfImage.match(/([\w\d_-]*)\.?[^\\\/]*$/i)[1];

// And then you can simply rename it with a replace
srcOfImage = srcOfImage.replace(filename, "even_better_logo");

console.log(srcOfImage);

// --> This way you keep your file extension
// You could also simply add a prefix or suffix on the filename
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you think there is maybe a solution by converting the image into base64 and... I'm not sure...or clone the image using canvas, without downloading at all ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can probably make a Flash plugin for this too. What is the aim of this? Maybe there is a GitHub library for file dialogs and you can try to do it that way.

Comment: The aim is to get any img on web as the source of `#imgt`, and not just linking the `url` but downloading it and get its `local url` and make it as source of `#imgt` at once, automatically, in one click.

Comment: I'm afraid that is impossible... Otherwise any website could access your personal data.